# Firefox CSS not working correctly

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser

My website that I'm currently developing, duncanhill.com.au, looks fine in chrome, safari and opera, however when I view it on firefox - it looks as if there is no stylesheet (see screenshots below). When I go into the inspector (I don't use firefox much) I can't even find the style.css file anywhere.

Screenshots:

**Firefox:**
[image: Firefox]

**Safari/Chrome/Opera:**
[image: Safari/Chrome/Opera]

Here is the link to the style.css file:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" type="css/text">
```

**Update:** As suggested by Andy, change the link type - `type="css/text"` to `type="text/css"`

How can I get the style.css file to work?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) instead.

Comment: Sorry Quentin, Fixed it!

Comment: How is a link to a external site with a screenshot better then a link to an external site with code?

Comment: Well, I don't have enough reputation to post the actual screenshot to stack overflow, the link should stay the same and this way people can see what I was talking about when they view the screenshot - I can't think of any other way that I can show what I mean.

Comment: Haha - yeah, I thought this was going to be a pretty simple question to answer (which it was) and it probably wasn't going to require code - but I'll put some in anyway for future people

Comment: Ok, done - That is as clear as I can possibly make it ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks as though you have the wrong `link` type for your `style.css` file. Some browsers will not recognise the link if this is incorrect.

Change:

```
type="css/text"
```

to

```
type="text/css"
```